# How to use NameReferenceConverter to create an object graph in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml

I whish to create a live object graph from XAML. This graph has nothing to do with WPF.

The main object describe a list of allowed objects (for example: A, B, C, ...) and some allowed relationship betwen these objects (for example A can have a relation with B and C, B can have a relation with A, and so on).

In XAML I wish to pre-declare the allowed object assigning to these object a `Name` property decorating the class with proper `RuntimeNameProperty`; then I whish to list allowed relationships referencing these names (I decorated the proper fields in relationship object with `NameReferenceConverter`).

The problem is I get an exception while parsing the XAML. Apparently the `NameReferenceConverter` need a context and receive instead a null.

Comment: Apparently this is "only" a design-time problem. At Runtime all work fine.

Comment: Apparently this is "only" a design-time "bug" introduced years-ago by Microsoft in an attempt to make WPF and Silverlight more close. At Runtime all work fine.